# Example of Lipshitz function which partial derivative doesnt exist

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I am now having a course of Diferential equations and professor asked us to try finding this example, but I am having a hard time to find out. 
Professor told us that there is example that satisfy this condition.
Can someone help me with this subject?

Comment: For functions from the reals to the reals, the absolute value function is Lipschitz and not differentiable at $0,$ and for such functions the derivative is also the (only) partial derivative. You should be able to modify this to get an example of a function from ${\mathbb R}^2$ to $\mathbb R$ (or for more variables, if two variables are not enough). For example, think about a function from a certain subset of ${\mathbb R}^2$ to $\mathbb R$ whose graph is a cone with vertical axis and vertex at the origin.